# Formatting a php variable into a php string with quotes

Tags: php, html

I've tried multiple ways to format this http string, like escaping the `"` that are present in `"user"` and the user's name, but the API I'm connecting to will not work with anything but `%22`, so:

```
https://url.com/search/search?p=[{"user":"abc123"}]
```

has to be formatted like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.com/search/search?p=[{%22user%22:%22abc123%22}]');
```

into this:

I need to replace `%22abc123%22` with the actual user from a PHP variable, so the code looks like this:

`[{%22user%22:%22 $phpVariable %22}]');`

and is still enclosed in the `%22`, but I cannot figure out how to get the variable into the string without causing the string to give me an error.  How do I do this (very simple) task?

Comment: Google for htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is, as I generally enclose things in single quotes, but when I enclosed the string in double quotes, it worked as it normally would, so my string is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.com/search/search?p=[{%22user%22:%22$phpVariable%22}]");
```